# Lagrangian homology classes in compact symplectic manifolds?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, lagrangian-submanifolds

Let $X$ be a compact symplectic $2n$-fold. Which classes in $H_{n}(X, \mathbb{Z})$ can be realized by embedded (or immersed, if that matters) Lagrangian submanifolds?

My question is motivated by following: for compact symplectic manifolds of dimension $4k$ a non-trivial restriction on Lagrangian homology classes comes from pairing with symplectic form $\int_{L}\omega^{k}=0$. I don't quite see how it can modified for symplectic manifolds of dimension $2(2k-1)$.

In fact, the stated necessary condition is sufficient for $k=1$ (symplectic 4-manifolds) as shown by J. Wolfson in chapter 3 of 'Conformal, Riemannian and Lagrangian Geometry: The 2000 Barrett Lectures' (there he also shows that any mid-homology class of compact simply-connected symplectic 6-fold can be represented by immersed Lagrangian). A related question is: is this condition sufficient for $4k$-dimensional symplectic manifolds, $k>1$?